# Ubuntu doesn't want to start WhatsUpp for Ubuntu. Error: "GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotAllowed: ..."

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I use WhatsUpp for Linux and one day when started I got the following message:

"GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotAllowed: This call is not available inside the sandbox"

The program doesn't start and there in only blank frame with that massage. I unstall and install again from Snapcraft that application with no effect.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Which software exactly and how did you install it? There are many unofficial **WhatsApp** clients, there isn't any official one. As such we need to know exactly which one you're using. Meanwhile you may want to use the web version (OS agnostic).

Comment: I have the same problem. Started today. I use Whatsapp for linux 1.4.4.

Comment: Haven't enough rep to answer, but I have the same issue. You can workaround in the short term by running 'snap run --gdb whatsapp-for-linux', then just say 'n' to debuginfo and 'cont' to finish opening. Keep in mind this effectively gives it root permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unofficial WhatsApp client by a third party available in the Snap Store. The only way you can get help is to contact the developer. You are better off running https://web.whatsapp.com in a browser.

Please see this video regarding Snaps.

[Switched to Linux](https://yewtu.be/watch?v=NE-AdmDGkEk)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the snap is missing the `network-status` plug, see this [forum post](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/help-gdbus-error-this-call-is-not-available-inside-the-sandbox/29969/5).